# Excel- Summation of value from duplicates lines

Tags: excel, numbers, duplicates, row, multiple-columns

I would like to know the most effecient method of adding values with duplicated lines along the column.

Example:

```
|Number | Type | Make | Model | (Header)
|   5   | Tiny | Gold |  1HC  |
|   7   | Small| Gold |  1HC  |
|   5   | Big  | Blue |  3HC  |
|   3   | Tiny | Gold |  0HC  |
```

So ideally I would like to detect duplicates along a column, such as `Tiny` or `Gold` in this case, and then evaluate the total sum of all `Numbers` under the same duplicate name. (So 5 + 3 = 8 if `Tiny` or 5+7+3=15 if `Gold`)

Much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried pivot tables?

Comment: Nice. Seems to be just the ticket to my question. Shall try it once I hit the office tomorrow. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If PivotTables are too much hassle for you, there are two formulas you can use.

SumIF: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/sumif-HP005209292.aspx (03+)

```
=SUMIF(TypeColumn, "Tiny", NumberColumn)
```

Will sum the number column from all rows where type is tiny, the first and third references are full ranges

Or if you want multiple matches

SumIFS: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/sumifs-function-HA102753226.aspx?CTT=1 (07+)

```
=SUMIFS(NumberColumn, TypeColumn, "Tiny", MakeColumn, "Gold")
```

Will sum the number column from all rows where type is tiny AND make is Gold, second and fourth arguments are ranges.